# Can PSN track my access code back to my account?

Tags: ps3, psn

I had my PS3 (along with my other valuables) stolen. I have since purchased another PS3 and still have some of the games, but all of the downloaded maps and codes reedemed are forever lost. However, my question is: I have the Madden 11 disk but not the case or booklet and PSN is asking for my access code to play online. Can they just track it back to my account? I am the only one using this account still!

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about Madden 11 per say and the access code that is required.

But if you go to `Playstation Network > Account Management > Transaction Management > Download List` you will see all the games/maps/dlcs etc that you have downloaded.

You can download them again on up to 5 ( can't find sources ) different PS3 systems and you can re-download them as many times as you want on the same system.

You should `activate` your ps3 and check this out.